# Changed debug enviroment from VB6 to Visual Studio

Tags: .net-3.5

I have already Visual Studio 2008 in my machine. Then I have installed VB6. After that when I try to debug of my .net problem through the JavaScript using the "debugger" keyword, it's open the VB6 environment. How can I change the my debug environment VB6 to Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 / Tools / Options / Debugging / Just-In-Time Debugging - check if the Script checkbox is checked.